# Python GUI project using Tkinter - stuck

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a guessing game that works in python, I would like to convert this code into a GUI.
I have made a previous math code for Pi. This I turned into a GUI.
[Screenshot of Pi calculator GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz0OP.png)

However, I want to now enter this code into a similar GUI:

```
from random import randint
numberToGuess = randint(0, 100)
userGuess = -1
message = "Guess the number (between 1 and 100).. "

while userGuess != numberToGuess:
    userGuess = int(input(message))
    if userGuess > numberToGuess:
        message = "Too high! Guess Lower: "
        elif userGuess < numberToGuess:
        message = "Too low! Guess Higher: "
        elif userGuess == numberToGuess:
         print("You Win, the number to guess was " + str(numberToGuess) + " indeed.")


          break
```

Comment: Since you already know how to create GUI application in tkinter, I wonder why you cannot do the same on this guessing game.

Comment: I have had an attempt. I have made 1 but was having issues with the loop. Back to the drawing board

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code that has `label`, `entry field` for user to enter number and `button` to guess the number. Function `guess_number` takes `entry field data` as `argument`. `guess_number` function will check if entered number is equal to randomly generated number, if it higher then generated number it will update 2nd `label` and user will see text that number entred in the field is too high, same will be done if entered number is too low. If number is quessed it will update `label text` to correct.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Number guesser")

l1 = tk.Label(text="Guess number:", anchor="w")
l1.pack(pady=10)
e1 = tk.Entry()
e1.pack(pady=10)
b1 = tk.Button(text="Guess:", anchor="w",command=lambda: guess_number(e1))
b1.pack(pady=10)
l2 = tk.Label(text="", anchor="w")
l2.pack(pady=10)

x = random.randint(0, 100)


def guess_number(num):
    number = num.get()
    print(x)
    if int(number) == x:
        l2.configure(text="Correct")
    elif int(number) > x:
        l2.configure(text="Your number is too high")
    elif int(number) < x:
        l2.configure(text="Your number is too low")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: oh my gosh, your code is very professional, it is easy to follow. I have never used this : 
b1 = tk.Button(text="Guess:", anchor="w",command=lambda: guess_number(e1))